# OpenLayers v2 -- Which Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, openlayers

[Google maps will soon be requiring API keys and billing details for their services](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/). How will this affect OpenLayers v2 applications that use a [Google Maps base layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Google-js.html)?

I'm unsure if OpenLayers is using the Google Maps Dynamic API, Static API, or Javascript API. Is there a difference between the Dynamic Maps API and the Javascript API?

Answer (score 0):

The example at: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/google.html
(you didn't provide your code) is using the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

Any application like that will require a key and be subject to the new billing requirements.